# How to get rid of C++Builder Warning "virtual function hides..."

Tags: c++, c++builder

Consider the following code example:

```
struct Base {
  virtual void foo(int) {}
  virtual void foo(int, double) {}

};

struct Derived : Base {
  virtual void foo(int) {}
};
```

In Embarcadero RAD Studio 2010 (C++Builder 2010), this gives the (correct) warning, telling us that `Base::foo(int,double)` is hidden by `Derived::foo(int)`. (The same warning is triggered by gcc's `-Woverloaded-virtual`) The usual thing to do is a using directive:

```
struct Derived : Base {
  virtual void foo(int) {}
  using Base::foo;
};
```

This silences the warning in gcc as expected, but does not help with C++Builder, although it makes the base class function visible to the compiler:

```
Derived d;
d.foo(2,3.4);
```

Compiles just fine with the using directive.

Are there any known workarounds to get rid of the warning in C++Builder, besides using `#pragma warn` or redefining the function à la

```
struct Derived : Base {
  virtual void foo(int) {}
  virtual void foo(int i, doubld d) {Base::foo(i,d); }
};
```

Comment: Regardless of any workaround found here, you should file a bug on this.

Comment: Wouldn't be worth the time. I found other bugs about about incorrect warnings that have been unattended for more than 5 years by Borland/Embarcadero. What I *should* do is get rid of the worst compiler/IDE I've ever used. Sadly, it's not that simple.

Comment: @ArneMertz I am the same situation, you got my sympathy.

Comment: define the method as pure virtual in the base class should get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring all forms of the method/function in the derived class removes the warning.

```
struct Derived : Base {
  virtual void foo(int, double) {}
  virtual void foo(int) {}
};
```

Comment: This changes the behaviour though, since your override does nothing.  And the question already said that they know about this option but preferred a better way.